# Add a unsupported tag into ASP.NET HtmlTextWriter

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to introduce HTML5 into my apps , but I'm struggling to find a way to use HtmlTextWriter with a new tag.

Would anyone be able to tell me how I can render an `<aside>`or a `<section>` tag using HtmlTextWriter and WriteFullBeginTag?

I'm using webforms - C# or VB solution accepted.

Thanks in advance

Sniffer

Answer (score 1):

writer.AddAttribute("attribute-name", "value");
    writer.RenderBeginTag("aside");

```
writer.RenderEndTag(); //aside
```

or

```
writer.WriteFullBeginTag("aside");
```

To write out the full tag with no attributes.

There is no enumeration support for it, but the writer gives you the ability to use strings to accomplish this...